# Mysql InnoDb is very slow on SELECT query

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I have a mysql table with following structure:

```
mysql> show create table logs \G;

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `request` text,
  `response` longtext,
  `msisdn` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shortcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `response_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `response_description` text,
  `transaction_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `system_owner` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `response_date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` text,
  `user_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'WEB',

  /**

  other columns here....

  other 18 columns here, with Type varchar and Text

  **/

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `transaction_name` (`transaction_name`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `msisdn` (`msisdn`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `username` (`username`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `request_date_time` (`request_date_time`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `system_owner` (`system_owner`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `shortcode` (`shortcode`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `response_code` (`response_code`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `channel` (`channel`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `request_date_time_2` (`request_date_time`),
  KEY `response_date_time` (`response_date_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59582405 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and it has more than 30000000 records in it.

```
mysql> select count(*) from logs;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 38962312 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1 min 17.77 sec)
```

Now the problem is that it is very slow, the result of select takes ages to fetch records from table.

My following sub query takes almost 30 minutes to fetch records of one day:

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT(sub.id) AS count,
    DATE(sub.REQUEST_DATE_TIME) AS transaction_date,
    sub.SYSTEM_OWNER,
    sub.transaction_name,
    sub.response,
    MIN(sub.response_time),
    MAX(sub.response_time),
    AVG(sub.response_time),
    sub.channel
FROM
    (SELECT 
        id,
            REQUEST_DATE_TIME,
            RESPONSE_DATE_TIME,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, REQUEST_DATE_TIME, RESPONSE_DATE_TIME) AS response_time,
            SYSTEM_OWNER,
            transaction_name,
            (CASE
                WHEN response_code IN ('0' , '00', 'EIL000') THEN 'Success'
                ELSE 'Failure'
            END) AS response,
            channel
    FROM
        logs
    WHERE
        response_code != ''
            AND DATE(REQUEST_DATE_TIME) BETWEEN '2016-10-26 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-27 00:00:00'
            AND SYSTEM_OWNER != '') sub
GROUP BY DATE(sub.REQUEST_DATE_TIME) , sub.channel , sub.SYSTEM_OWNER , sub.transaction_name , sub.response
ORDER BY DATE(sub.REQUEST_DATE_TIME) DESC , sub.SYSTEM_OWNER , sub.transaction_name , sub.response DESC;
```

I have also added indexes to my table, but still it is very slow.

Any help on how can I make it fast ?

**EDIT:**
Ran the above query using EXPLAIN

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys              | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL                       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 16053297 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | logs       | ALL  | system_owner,response_code | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 32106592 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: You'll need to take a better look at your indexes.  I imagine it's going to take a bit of time to figure out - you're going to need them spanning multiple columns since you've got such a lot of where/group/order criteria.  I assume you've run an `EXPLAIN` to see what it's struggling with?

Comment: One thing you could try is changing `AND DATE(REQUEST_DATE_TIME) BETWEEN '2016-10-26 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-27 00:00:00'` to `AND REQUEST_DATE_TIME>'2016-10-26' AND REQUEST_DATE_TIME<'2016-10-27'`

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that by default, InnoDB isn't allocated much resource.  Do you know what your utilisation is?

Comment: @calcinai updated my post and added the output of EXPLAIN

Comment: Looking at that it suggests that your logs table has 32m records, and the sub query is returning 16m of them; this isn't a small enough number for it to be worth using the index on request_date_time (very crude rule of thumb, unless the index excludes >2/3 of the rows MySQL will ignore it for the WHERE clause). This also means the sub query is returning a massive number of rows for the outer query, and it will not have the benefit of any indexes

Comment: @Kickstart sorry, but I did not get what you are saying. apologies.
can you please explain what should I do here ?

Comment: Looking at your EXPLAIN, the sub query is processing 32106592 rows (~32 million). This should only be returning a single days worth of records due to the WHERE clause in it. However the outer query is processing 16053297 rows (~16 million). This is almost half the original records, so MySQL does not think it is worth using any index in the sub query.

Comment: @ChrisLear I have tried using > and < in request_date_time, and got the result fast, will this also work, if I use `REQUEST_DATE_TIME>'2016-10-26 15:05:55' AND REQUEST_DATE_TIME<'2016-10-27 20:25:15'` ?

Comment: You can certainly try it :). There's no reason why it shouldn't work

Comment: You can just remove the DATE() function in the WHERE clause. It isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: @Kickstart what I understood from your 2nd last comment, is that in my current query, indexes are not helpful, right ?
Also I have removed the date() function from where clause, now select is working fast as compared to before, but still not fast enough.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be using the INDEX on REQUEST_DATE_TIME. It might if you narrow the range down more. But it seems strange that you have so many logs for just 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, the query must scan the entire table.

But first, let's air a possible bug:

```
AND DATE(REQUEST_DATE_TIME) BETWEEN '2016-10-26 00:00:00'
                                AND '2016-10-27 00:00:00'
```

Gives you the logs for *two* days -- all of the 26th and *all* of the 27th.  Or is that what you really wanted?  (`BETWEEN` is *inclusive*.)

But the performance problem is that the index will not be used because `request_date_time` is hiding inside a function (`DATE`).

Jump forward to a better way to phrase it:

```
AND REQUEST_DATE_TIME >= '2016-10-26'
AND REQUEST_DATE_TIME  < '2016-10-26' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

- A `DATETIME` can be compared against a date.
- Midnight of the morning of the 26th is included, but midnight of the 27th is not.
- You can easily change `1` to however many days you wish -- without having to deal with leap days, etc.
- This formulation allows the use of the index on `request_date_time`, thereby cutting back severely on amount of data to be scanned.

As for other tempting areas:

- `!=` does not optimize well, so no 'composite' index is likely to be beneficial.
- Since we can't really get past the `WHERE`, no index is useful for `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`.
- My comments about `DATE()` in `WHERE` do not apply to `GROUP BY`; no change needed.

Why have the subquery?  I think it can be done in a single layer.  This will eliminate a rather large temp table.  (Yeah, it means 3 uses of `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`, but that is probably a lot cheaper than the temp table.)

How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

If my comments are not enough, and if you frequently run a query like this (over a day or over a date range), then we can talk about building and maintaining a [*Summary table*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/), which might give you a 10x speedup.